# Does acquiring and releasing java monitor locks (synchronized blocks, reentrant locks etc) requires context switch to kernel space?

Tags: java, concurrency, jvm, locking, java.util.concurrent

AFAIK, Every object in Java has a mark word. The first word (the mark word) is used for storing locking information, either through a flag if only one thread is acquiring the lock or pointing to a lock monitor object if there is contention between different threads, and in both the cases, compare and swap construct is used for acquiring the lock.

But according to this link - 
https://www.baeldung.com/lmax-disruptor-concurrency

> To deal with the write contention, a queue often uses locks, which can cause a context switch  to the kernel. When this happens the processor involved is likely to lose the data in its caches.

What am I missing ?

Comment: cache clearing when monitor locking is required by java memory model anyway.

Comment: @AlexeiKaigorodov the JMM requires that the implementation ensures visibility. At no place does it mandates clearing the caches. I also doubt that entering the kernel mode causes cache clearing on any architecture. That statement is an attempt to describe the associated costs of a context switch, which are indeed there and significant, but the description is misleading at best.

Comment: how are you going to achieve visibility without cache clearing? Cache content obscures the real state of the memory.

Comment: @AlexeiKaigorodov the presence of caches is an implementation detail, not a thing mandated by the specification. Not even “real state of the memory” is a thing, as the JMM works in terms of *happens-before* relationships between actions, in other words, the visibility established between two threads having such a relationship doesn’t need to affect how other threads see the memory. In practice, visibility between threads can be established on x86/64 by syncing the caches, without needing to access the main memory. Further, every singlecore architecture supports visibility without cache flushes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Neither, `synchronized` nor the standard `Lock` implementations, require a context switch into the kernel when locking *uncontended* or unlocking. These operations indeed boil down to an atomic cas or write.

The performance critical aspect is the *contention*, i.e. when trying to acquire the monitor or lock and it’s not available. Waiting for the availability of the monitor or lock implies putting the thread into a waiting state and reactivating it when the resource became available. The performance impact is so large, that you don’t need to worry about CPU caches at all.

For this reason, typical implementations perform some amount of spinning, rechecking the availability of the monitor or lock in a loop for some time, when there is a chance of becoming available in that time. This is usually tied to the number of CPU cores. When the resource becomes available in that time, these costs can be avoided. This, however, usually requires the acquisition to be allowed to be *unfair*, as a spinning acquisition may overtake an already waiting thread.

Note that the linked article says before your cited sentence:

> Queues are typically always close to full or close to empty due to the differences in pace between consumers and producers.

In such a scenario, the faster threads will sooner or later enter a condition wait, waiting for new space or new items in a queue, even when they acquired the lock without contention. So in this specific scenario, the associated costs are indeed there and unavoidable when using a simple queue implementation.